# worker added but not present in kubectl get nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm setting up a 2-node Kubernetes system, following the Docker Multi-Node [instructions](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode.html).

My problem is that `kubectl get nodes` only shows the master, not the worker node as well.

- The setup appears to have worked, with all the expected containers running (as far as I know)
- I've confirmed that networking works via flannel.
- The subnet of the work node appears in the master's subnet list.

So everything looks good, except the node isn't showing up.

My questions:

1. Am I right in thinking the worker node should now be visible from 'get nodes'?
2. Does it matter whether the MASTER_IP used to do the setup was the master node's public IP address, or the docker IP? (I've tried both..)
3. Where do I start with debugging this?

Any pointers gratefully accepted...

Versions:

- Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS on both master and worker
- Kubernetes v1.1.4
- hyperkube:v1.0.3

Comment: hard to tell from the info you are giving: we need to see your config. Most likely the worker node is not talking to the master for some reason, and it could be many things (like bad certificates, bad config of the master IP in the worker kubelet... )

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MrE ; could you tell me what config you need to see? I can tell that the worker node can talk to the master node by starting an ubuntu container on each and pinging the other, so I can see that the flannel network is up.

Comment: i think the relevant info is in the kube-config and the params you pass to kubelet on each node (whether it's in a service or command line)

Comment: # kubectl config view shows an empty config on both, which is definitely different to the working kubernetes setup I've got working on Google Cloud. 

kubelet gets started by master.sh and worker.sh from the kubernetes repo. I've posted those at http://pastebin.com/9Mntiwen

The version is 1.0.3 and I've tried both the public and docker IPs for the MASTER_IP in worker.sh

Comment: I'm looking at the kubectl logs on the minion, and it looks as though it may be a problem to do with the IPv6 address...

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @MrE for replying and nudging me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own #cloudplatform question...

It turned out to be a problem in worker.sh in Kubernetes v1.1.4.

kubectl is called with "--hostname-override=$(hostname -i)"

On this machine, that returns the IPv6 address.

The K8s code is trying to turn that into a DNS name, and fails.

So looking at the log file for the kubectl container, we see this:

```
I0122 15:57:33.891577    1786 kubelet.go:1942] Recording NodeReady event message for node 2001:41c9:1:41f::131
I0122 15:57:33.891599    1786 kubelet.go:790] Attempting to register node 2001:41c9:1:41f::131
I0122 15:57:33.894076    1786 kubelet.go:793] Unable to register 2001:41c9:1:41f::131 with the apiserver: Node "2001:41c9:1:41f::131" is invalid: [metadata.name: invalid value '2001:41c9:1:41f::131': must be a DNS subdomain (at most 253 characters, matching regex [a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*): e.g. "example.com", metadata.labels: invalid value '2001:41c9:1:41f::131': must have at most 63 characters, matching regex (([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?: e.g. "MyValue" or ""]
```

So that's my problem. Take that out and it all works well.

So in answer to my 3 questions:

1. Yes, the worker node should be visible immediately in 'get nodes'.
2. I don't think it matters for getting it to work; it may matter for security reasons.
3. First step after checking that the basic networking is right and the containers are running: look at the log file for the new node's kubectl container.

Update: I wrote this blog post to explain how I got it working http://blog.willmer.org/2016/11/kubernetes-bytemark/

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can you please tell me how to get the logs and also where is worker.sh located? Thanks.